# Preg_match, Replace and back to string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

sorry but i cant solve my problem, you know , Im a noob.
I need to find something in string with preg_match.. then replace it with new word using preg_replace, that's ok, but I don't understand how to put replaced word back to that string.
This is what I got

```
$text ='zda i "zda"';
preg_match('/"(\w*)"/', $text);
$najit = '/zda/';
$nahradit = '&#122;&#100;&#97;';
$o = '/zda/';
$a = 'if';
$ahoj = preg_replace($najit, $nahradit, $match[1]);
```

Please, can you help me once again?

Comment: Can you help us out, please? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Howard - replace the word zda in $text with the word if, but no word "zda" (in quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use e.g. the following code utilizing negative lookarounds to accomplish what you want:

```
$newtext = preg_replace('/(?<!")zda|zda(?!")/', 'if', $text)
```

It will replace any occurence of `zda` which is not enclosed in quotes on both sides (i.e. in `U"Vzda"W` the `zda` will be replaced because it is not enclosed directly into quotes).

Comment: "U"Vzda"W the zda will be replaced because it is not enclosed directly into quotes)." Is there some way how to not replace that word?
Its a sort of translator, and i want to not replace everything in qoutation. Hope you understand me.. thanks

Comment: What about `"X"YzdaZ"`: is it now enclosed or not? You have to specify much better what you want then.

Comment: I want to replace just `zda` but if there is "Hello zda" dont replace..
Sorry for disturbing,but I'm desperate.
Thanks